# React — onScroll listener for parent element?

Tags: reactjs

How can I add an onScroll listener in a component to catch a scroll of a parent element?

```
class ChildDiv extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  handleScrollOfParent() {
    // do stuff when parent <main> scrolls;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="child" onScroll={this.handleScrollOfParent.bind(this)}>
        // content with overflow: hidden and scroll handled by parent MAIN.
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default ChildDiv;
```

Rendered in a parent main, like this `<main><ChildDiv /></main>` and I want to catch the scroll of the main.

Comment: Have you found your solution yet, I've just posted an answer below

Comment: Forwarding Refs will  help to  listen to scroll event of  "main" inside  your childDiv component

Answer (score 3):

You could either:

1) try to grab the parent node from the child component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode.addEventListener(...
}
```

2) pass the parent node as props and attach listener after rendered:

In parent:

```
render{
  return(
    <div className="parent" ref={(elem)=>{this.node=elem}}>
      <Child parentNode={this.node}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and in child (parentNode is still undefined in constructor, check in next props):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
  newProps.parentNode.addEventListener(...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to React's nature, which is passing props from Parent down to Children, so when you want the Child element to update its parent, you need to create a function on Parent, and pass to the Child as props

Please also refer to my answer to a similar issue (how to trigger the parent component to do something from the child/grandchild/or great-grandchild):

[Re-initializing class on redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601156/re-initializing-class-on-redirect/43602364#43602364)

In your case, we may do something like this:

1/ Create a function on Parent that trigger the Parent itself to do something:

```
import React from 'react';

class Parent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // ...
  }

  doSomeThingOnParent = () => {
    // do whatever you want with this Parent component, setState, forceUpdate etc.
  }

  render(){
    // ...
    <Child doSomeThingOnParent={this.doSomeThingOnParent} />
    // ...
  }
}
```

2/ On Child Component, trigger the above function using onScroll:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="child" onScroll={this.props.doSomeThingOnParent}>
        // your content
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

However, you cannot render the Parent by your mentioned way, which is:

You should use like the Parent's render method above, and also set the CSS to allow overflow for your Child component

Comment: OP specifically said that they wanted to catch the scroll event for `main` not for `child`. In your example you are showing how to get a child scroll event in the main, which is the opposite. @igorsvee's solution can accomplish what the OP was asking for. Another solution would be to use a scroll handler in the parent and then call a method in the child component by using a `ref` on `<Child />`.

Comment: @vinnymac thanks for your comment, it seems that a misunderstand really happened here ^^ Actually the first sentence of the OP is "How can I add an onScroll listener in a component to catch a scroll of a parent element?", which directs me to the above example. However, the OP's code example somehow shows the opposite way ^^ so actually, if the opposite way is truly requested, then you're right, using componentWillReceiveProps may achieve that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could define a state variable in the parent component that would store the current scrollTop value (assuming vertical scrolling) and update in every time the `scroll` event happens and then pass this variable to the `ChildDiv` which could detect that the variable has changed in  `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
if(this.props.yourVariable != nextProps.yourVariable){
// scroll event was fired => scroll position changed
}
```

Comment: This is the real answer for "How can I add an onScroll listener in a component to catch a scroll of a parent element?"