# Re-initializing class on redirect

Tags: reactjs

I am currently at `http://example.com/parentdir/module/2/`

This URL actually loads the Module.js class as indicated in the following route:

```
<Route exact path={"/parentdir/module/:id"} component={Module} />
```

This is contained within `<BrowserRouter>` and `<Switch>` elements as defined in my index.js file.

The Module class has a `constructor` and `componentWillMount` methods. These set up the initial details and load information for record #2. Everything works fine so far.

Now, my problem is that in a grandchild component of Module.js I redirect to another page such as page 3 with the following Redirect:

```
return (
        <Redirect to="/parentdir/module/3/" />
)
```

The constructor or componentWillMount do not run so record #3 does not properly load. Is this because this component is already loaded in memory from when record #2 was loaded? What is the best way to reload Module.js so it properly loads record #3? Do I somehow have to reinitialize the class? Or do I somehow have to pass the data from the grandchild component back up to the module class? The latter approach would seem to be tedious.

Just to clarify, if I go directly to http://example.com/parentdir/module/3 in the address bar everything works properly, but if I redirect to this same address within the ReactJS environment it does not work properly.

**Update**

Two answers to my question have been given so far. One solution suggests using componentWillReceiveProps. The other solution suggests passing a method as a prop down to the child and then to the grandchild. Are there pros and cons to using each of these approaches or is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: You have to make use of `componentWillReceiveProps` in `module.js`. In its arguments you'll get the `nextprops`. You can compare it with `this.props` to see if it has changed. Based on `nextProps` you can reset your components state accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` is passed as a `prop` in the form of `this.props.params.id` so you should use the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method which runs everytime the `props` change which is what is happening in your case.

The `componentWillMount` method will not run when you navigate from `/parentdir/module/2` to `/parentdir/module/3` as the component is already `mounted`. It will only run when you navigate from some other component (when you go directly for example).

In your `Module` component add this lifecycle method

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
      if(nextProps.params.id != this.props.params.id){
          //load information etc (whatever you are doing in componentWillMount)
       }
}
```

What is happening is that when it receives the newer set of `props` it's comparing if the param `id` has changed (all route params live in the `params` object in `props`) and when it sees there is a change it carries out the logic. The comparison is not really necessary and you can add the logic as is in  the `componentWillReceiveProps` method but that would be inefficient as it is called everytime the `props` object changes (might not be the `id` param at all).

Comment: How does your example compare with thinhvo0108's example. Both seem like valid approaches. Also, I find your last sentence a bit unclear.

Comment: In the last sentence I meant that you can skip the `if (nextProps.params.id != this.props.params.id)` conditional but this would mean that the methods would be called any time any props change as `componentWillReceiveProps` is triggered then. This might mean that the methods are being run even when you are not navigating to other pages and some other `props` are being changed.

Comment: My method is more of the standard variety as the flow is simple and one way. You navigate to a page, the prop changes, the functions are called. This is far more straight forward then passing a function down to children and grandchildren and then calling that function when there are changes in the child/grandchild. Also it seems really ineffective because as soon as you run `updateGrandParent` or `updateParent` the `render` function on the grandparent/parent will be triggered which means the children will be rendered again (as they are descendants of the main component) with same information.

Comment: That's why I suggested using Flux or Redux, which will eliminate the complexity of passing props through many levels of child-components. However, in theory, componentWillReceiveProps will be executed when props are passed into the component, but after new props are passed, the component will not update itself unless we use either forceUpdate or setState. I think setState will be suggested here, too. Actually, my above approaching way just gives an explanation on how to pass a callback on the parent to its children, and of course we can also use setState in that callback function. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**componentWillMount()** and **componentDidMount()** will only be executed once!

(According to React Component Life Cycle https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)

If you want your Module to be updated every time the grandchild module updates, you need to create a function in your Module, and pass it along as **Props** to the child, and grandchild modules as well (in the main Module's render method)

That function (*updateThisModule*) and your render method will look something like this:

EDITED VERSION BELOW: (this is just a demonstration on how to trigger a callback function on parent-component from multi-level-child-component, we can actually do whatever in that callback)

```
import React from 'react';

class Module extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // ...
  }

  updateThisModule = () => {
    // We can do whatever we want here, either forceUpdate the component
    // or setState, which will also trigger this component to update itself
    // (using setState is more natural, though)
    // *** OPTION 1
    // this.forceUpdate();
    // *** OPTION 2
    // this.setState({
    //   someState: 'someValue',
    //   ..
    // });
    // *** ...
    // ...
  }

  render(){
    // ...
    <ChildModule updateParent={this.updateThisModule} />
    // ...
  }
}
```

Likewise, do the same thing in your child-module's render method (to pass that function down 1 more level to the grandchild-module):

```
class ChildModule extends React.Component {
  ...
  render(){
    // ...
    <GrandChildModule updateGrandParent={this.props.updateParent} />
    // ...
  }
}
```

After that, in the Grand-Child-Module, we need a trigger that call the top-level Module to be updated, I suggest you trigger this in the componentDidUpdate() function. Then, the Grand-Child-Module may look like this:

```
class GrandChildModule extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     // ...
  }

  componentDidUpdate() { 
    // this will be executed every time this grand-child-module updates itself
    // we will then trigger the update function upward to the parent's level first, then the grand-parent's level (which is your main Module)
    this.props.updateGrandParent(); 
  }

  render(){
    // ...
  }
}
```

The above code is written in ES6, if you write yours in different way, feel free to post it here, then we can modify your code together to make it work!

PS: passing function as props along to child's component is also the main idea of pure React components. However, if your module-hierarchy is too deep (with many child, grandchild, great-grandchild etc.,) you may consider using Flux or Redux

Comment: forceUpdate() really shouldn't be used. All renders should ideally happen with changes in state or props.

Comment: So, if I remove the forceUpdate line, and issue a setState in its place it would work best? How does this example compare with mrinalmech's example using componentWillReceiveProps. Both seem like valid approaches.

Comment: Using setState will work well, because the nature of React is to rerender the component when its state changes. @mrinalmech using setState is better than using forceUpdate though. However, I just gave an example on how to trigger a function on Parent, and we can do whatever we want in that trigger-function. Thanks